# The default Truffle Drizzle Box gets stuck initializing the website

Tags: javascript, html, ethereum, truffle

I am using the default Truffle Drizzle Box without adding any changes to it. When I compile and build and run, the localhost page only says "Loading...".

Here is the code from the App.js file:

```js
import React from "react";
import { DrizzleContext } from "@drizzle/react-plugin";
import { Drizzle } from "@drizzle/store";
import drizzleOptions from "./drizzleOptions";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
import "./App.css";

const drizzle = new Drizzle(drizzleOptions);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <DrizzleContext.Provider drizzle={drizzle}>
      <DrizzleContext.Consumer>
        {drizzleContext => {
          const { drizzle, drizzleState, initialized } = drizzleContext;

          if (!initialized) {
            return "Balls..."
          }

          return (
            <MyComponent drizzle={drizzle} drizzleState={drizzleState} />
          )
        }}
      </DrizzleContext.Consumer>
    </DrizzleContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if you need other files, but I cloned the entire box from https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle. I'm also running ganache for my testnet. I'm assuming this issue is because the drizzle box was created a while back and hasn't really been updated accordingly, so this might not be the best place for me to try to learn dapps.